# Newest question(s) not visible

Tags: bug, questions

When a new question is asked, a message appears at the top of the questions feed, saying

`x new questions`

When I click it, the newly asked questions are visible. After refreshing the page, these new questions aren't there any more. They re-appear some time later after another refresh.

If this would be relevant, I'm using Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 m.

Comment: Yes, that happens and it's a bit annoying. The `x new questions` thingy (that's websockets based) is a bit too eager to show us what's new, while on the other hand the question list has (and always had) a noticeable lag (that I think is intentional, because of the editing grace period). You can easily reproduce all this by having a tab open on the questions list, and ask a new question on another (that's _not_ an invitation to test it out, unless of course you have a great question to ask ;)